# How to pass object id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relationship between two models

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end
```

I have `category_id` in products table but When I create a new product in my products table
`category_id` is null. I am new to rails can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, a thought - most of the time, products have many categories, but each category also contains many products. Perhaps your association should be a many-to-many? On to your actual question.

If I understand correctly, your question is really about how to create categories and products that are related to each other in the database, i.e. how to set the value of `product_id` when building a new category.

For clarity in case you need it, product_id would only be set for a **category**. The category, after all, belongs to that product, so it has to hold its owner's ID.

So, let's say you want to build a new category that belongs to an existing product - you can do this:

```
# in your view, where you link from products/show.html.erb to category/new.html.erb
<%= link_to "Build new category for this product", new_category_url(:id => @product.id) %>
    # you must have @product defined, and you also must have 
    # 'resources :categories' in your routes file

# in your controller action categories/new, set the new category's product id:
def new
  @category = Category.new(:product_id => params[:id])
end

# include a hidden field to contain the product_id in your new form
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :product_id %>
  ... other fields, labels, etc.
<% end %>

# save the record as you normally would (analogous to the code in your comment to @Chowlett).
@category = Category.new(params[:category])
if @category.save
  redirect_to :action => "list", :notice => "Category saved successfully."
else
  render :action => "new"
end
```

The above code allows you to build a product, then each category one-by-one. So, we are building your product first, then including a link from the product/show page to your category/new form, passing in the ID of the product you want that category to be part of.

If you want to build a product and some categories **at the same time**, it is a bit more complicated. For more information on this, take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 (this is the first of a three-part series) and https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form. I don't suggest this course of action unless you are very comfortable with the above basics. I once got mired in this code for a week when I was new to Rails!

Comment: Great Answer! I have a two part question and this answered the first part perfectly. If you have a minute, would you mind taking a crack at the second part of my question found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813528/how-to-pass-foreign-key-attributes-down-through-a-nested-form-in-rails-3)? It has to do with this question, only with a nested form.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you have the `_id` field in the wrong table. If `Category belongs_to :product`, then your categories table needs a field `product_id`.

Look at it this way: each Product can have *many* Categories - so what *single* value would you expect to find in a `category_id` field?

If you still have problems after correcting that, let me know.

**Edit:** Once you've got your tables set up, you still need to tell Rails what the link should be. You've got a few options. Assuming you've got a Category in hand, your best bet is `new_prod = my_cat.create_product()`. Alternatively, you can use `new_prod = Product.create(:category => my_cat)`.

Later on, you can associate the models together like this:

```
my_prod.category = my_cat
my_prod.save
```

Comment: I created a column called product_id in categories table and created a new product still category_id is null?? Do I need to pass a category_id in product_controller in new action??                                                                             def new
    @product = Product.new
  end
  
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    if @product.save
          redirect_to :action => 'list'
    else
          @categories = Category.find(:all)
          render :action => 'new' 
    end
               
  end

Comment: correct me, if I'm wrong, but if in Product you use attr_accessible, Product.create :category => my_cat will not assign the category.