# How to pass foreign key attributes down through a nested form in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, nested-forms

I have three models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :balancesheets
   has_many :investment_assets, :through => :balancesheets

class Balancesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :client
   has_many :investment_assets, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :investment_assets, :allow_destroy => true

class InvestmentAsset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :balancesheet
       belongs_to :client
```

I have two questions that have to do with the foreign key client_id. First, when I create a new balancesheet, I use collection_select to select the client from the list. I would rather put the new balancesheet link on the client show page and just pass the client id through to the form so I don't have to choose a client from a list or type it in a field. So first, how do I do that?

Second, the investment_asset model is nested in the balancesheet form. Everything works just fine, except the client_id attribute for the investment_asset is blank. Im not sure why because my associations seem to be okay. So the question is, how do I pass this client_id attribute down through the nested form? I can post models or controllers, just let me know.

**UPDATE** I have since found the answer to my first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719499/how-to-pass-object-id). However, I am still trying to figure out the second part based on that answer, which is, how do I pass this client_id down through a nested form? To show how it worked passing user id when creating a balancesheet, here is the client show page link:

```
<%= link_to 'New BalanceSheet',new_balancesheet_path(:id => @client.id) %>
```

In the balancesheet form I have a hidden field:

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :client_id %>
```

And in the Balancesheet Controller this is the new action:

```
 @balancesheet = Balancesheet.new(:client_id => params[:id])
```

This works just fine. So for an investment_asset I am using [Ryan Bates nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) which has a little bit different syntax for a link. So inside the balancesheet form the link to add a new investment_asset is:

```
 <%= f.link_to_add "Add asset", :investment_assets %>
```

I can't figure out how to pass the user id like I did on the balancesheet with:

```
(:id => @client.id)
```

I can put the same thing in a new action in the investment_asset controller and add a hidden field, but I'm not sure how to pass it in on the link. Thoughts?

Comment: just for initial clarity, do you have hidden fields in your nested form to hold the client ID? Second, is it possible to instead set the client ID separately in the `create` action of your controller? If ownership is particularly important in your app you may like to avoid trusting any client ID submitted by a user. This second part only works, of course, if the client is authenticated and submitting the form themselves.

Comment: @sscirrus - I do have hidden fields in the forms. Use of this application will be staff inside our firm, not for public or users to sign up, so it has to grab the current id not from a logged in user, but from the client page that is being viewed. I was able to pass the user ID down to balancesheet when it is created, but still can't do it for investment_assets. They are in a nested form following the Railscast tutorial [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), in fact, they don't even have a controller. Does this clarify at all? Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a total hack for all I know, but all I know is very limited. What I ended up doing here was user jQuery to take the id from the balancesheet and force it into a hidden field for investment_asset. jQuery:

```
// get the value from the balancesheet hidden field that contains the user_id value
var balsheetclientid = jQuery('#hiddenid').attr('value'); 
// insert it into the value attribute in the hidden field with class name .iaclientid
jQuery('.iaclientid').val(balsheetclientid)
```

Then my hidden field looks like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :client_id, :class => 'iaclientid', :value => '' %>
```

It works just fine. Hopefully that's a valid way of doing it.