# Rails copy id from one model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, record, rails-activerecord

I have an employee model is follows :

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :blood_group_id, :caste_id, :category_id, :emp_dob, :emp_email,     :emp_fathername, :emp_fname, :emp_full_name, :gender_id, :emp_id, :emp_lname, :emp_loc_master_id, :emp_mname, :emp_mobile_no, :emp_permanent_address, :emp_phone_no, :religion_id

  has_many:postings
  has_many:dependents
  has_many:qualifications

  belongs_to:gender
  belongs_to:category
  belongs_to:religion
  belongs_to:caste
  belongs_to:blood_group
end
```

And a qualifications model :

```
class Qualification < ActiveRecord::Base
              attr_accessible :Remarks, :employee_id, :qualification_name_id, :qualification_type_id, :specialisation_id, :university_id, :year

              belongs_to:employee
              belongs_to:qualification_type
              belongs_to:qualification_name
              belongs_to:specialisation
              belongs_to:university
            end
```

All the associations are properly made. Now I can create a new employee by the employee form and also I can give him qualifications by going to the qualifications form (EXPLICITLY) and selecting the employee from dropdown and and giving him qualifications.

But what I want to do is this:
create an "add qualifications" button which allows me to add qualifications to the employee under observation and implicitly takes the employee id and I am just required to add the qualifications and click create.

Comment: then what's the deal. Add the qualification button and onclick show the qualifications to add. This should be contained within a form as it needs to be submitted. More better approach- use ajax to submit. This will not require form as well.

Comment: Thnx for reply Saurabh ... 
Im not getting the concept as to what to write in the qualifications link button ...
i can redirect to the qualification page from my employee page ... 
but there i have to select the employee again ... which mars the purpose ... 
It needs to get the employee id automatically from the employee from where i got redirected ...

Comment: Make the "Edit User" page and add the qualification drop down or checkboxes if user can select many. Then update button to update what user selected or changed.

Comment: No no that could have been done :) ... i know that one ...
the thing is ... i need to maintain another table altogether for the qualifications as u can see from my model ... 
i want to be able to add qualifications in a after redirecting from an employee table ... 
The employee id should be in the qualifications table automatically ....

Comment: **Off-topic suggestion:** Do you have a scenario where an employee has many qualifications and at the same time a qualification is related to many employees. If this is the case, then you should change your model structure.

Comment: If the mentioned structure is correct then Do you want to just pass the related employee id to the qualification form? Or You just want to update/create qualifications for an employee in the edit employee page? In the later case the qualifications table will also be updated as you have shown concerns about it in your last comment.

Comment: Hey ppl ... c according to my current setup ... this is the only way i can add qualifications to a employee ... 
ie by going to my qualifications master -> selecting from employees -> and then adding his qualification 
as such :
http://i.imgur.com/wyFSNGB.png

This is reflected in the employees page as such :
http://i.imgur.com/D4wd6yq.png

what i want to do is click on the new button(currently dummy) such that it redirects to the qualification page selecting "Akash" automatically (since i clicked new while viewing the details of Akash) and just add the qualifications :) ./...

Comment: This would eventually allow me ...to add training, dependents,leaves etc etc ... with similar logic ... 

The database is HIGHLY normalised ... with just primary keys linking stuff ... 

i dont want to suffocate my employee table with too many colums ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx for all the help ...

this is what finally worked :

I added this to my qualifications controller ...

```
class QualificationsController < InheritedResources::Base
def new
    @qualification = Qualification.new(:employee_id => params[:id])
end

def create
    @qualification = Qualification.new(params[:qualification])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @qualification.save
            format.html { redirect_to @qualification, notice: 'Qualification was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @qualification, status: :created, location: @qualification }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @qualification.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
end
end
```

then I added this to my employee_show view page ...

```
<%= link_to "Add A New Qualification for this Employee", new_qualification_url(:id => @employee.id) %>
```

And i added this to my qualifications form :

```
 <%= simple_form_for @qualification, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

  <%= f.association :employee,label_method: :emp_full_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false, :as => :hidden%>
<%= f.association :employee,label_method: :emp_full_name, value_method: :id, include_blank: false, disabled: true%>
```

And after adding the employee this is what helped me go back to the employee from where i came :

```
<%= link_to t('.back', :default => t("helpers.links.back")),
          employee_path(@qualification.employee_id), :class => 'btn'  %>
```

Im using simple_form which is an awesome DSL FTW :D :D :D .....

And everything is fine as wanted :) ... 
Thnx for everyone's help ... 
I posted here so tht someone like my problem can sort out in future :D ...

Regards

Comment: This is the post which helped me understand the concepts :) ...
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5721624/1549731

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic form, send data to controller, parse data server-side.
I suggest using KnockoutJS for this, here is a similar example:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html

Comment: Thnx sir for the response ...
But shouldnt there be a simple way ... 
Im really new to rails ... 

conceptually cant i just get the employee id using some SQL on the controller when i when iclick the add qualifications button ...

such that the employee id is pre fethced and i just need to add the qulifications ... 

Thnx soo much ... 
Im really having a hard time finding the syntax ...

Comment: if u want to make it easier, then make static number of qualifications (like 3) and just use standard form

Comment: Thnx very much for the help sir :) ... 

Ill explore n learn more ... since i have to have to get this particular requirement correctly ... 

Sincere Regards
-Sky